Integrated API gateway with a lambda authorizer but when invoking it for allow policy it is returning Internal Server Error, for deny its working fine
This is the template I am using : https://github.com/devashish234073/cloud-experiments/blob/main/aws/cloudformations/lambda_api_gw_authorizer/lambda_api_gw_authorizer.yaml
When I am calling the api gateway endpoint from postman for with value "allow" in the Authorization header I am getting "Internal Server Error"
But for "deny" I am getting proper response:

For the lambda authorizer I am using the code from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html
From the template this is the lambda authorizer part:
AuthorizerForAPIGW:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "authorizer-for-api-gw"
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaFuncRoleForAuthorizer.Arn
      Handler: src/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      MemorySize: 320
      Timeout: 20
      InlineCode: |
        exports.handler =  function(event, context, callback) {
          var token = event.authorizationToken;
          switch (token) {
            case 'allow':
              callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn));
              break;
            case 'deny':
              callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn));
              break;
            case 'unauthorized':
              callback("Unauthorized");   // Return a 401 Unauthorized response
              break;
            default:
              callback("Error: Invalid token"); // Return a 500 Invalid token response
          }
        };
        var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
          var authResponse = {};  
          authResponse.principalId = principalId;
          if (effect && resource) {
            var policyDocument = {};
            policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; 
            policyDocument.Statement = [];
            var statementOne = {};
            statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; 
            statementOne.Effect = effect;
            statementOne.Resource = resource;
            policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
            authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
            console.log("statement",statementOne);
            console.log("policyDocument",policyDocument);
          }
          authResponse.context = {
            "stringKey": "stringval",
            "numberKey": 123,
            "booleanKey": true
          };
          return authResponse;
        }


Looks like this section of the cloudformation template under api gateway had the issue, I commented it:

And instead added the below one in lambda definition which fixed it :

Now deny authorization is still working as before and with allow I am getting the response from the lambda:

